# Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue. waiting for selector `ul` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded Puppeteer Crawler

Tags: web-crawler, puppeteer, crawlee

WARN PuppeteerCrawler: Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue. waiting for selector `.show-more-less-html__markup` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded {"id":"nWhJU8Vn62Xzbr3","url":"https://www.somesite.com/view/result_search-card","retryCount":1}

```js
import { RequestQueue, PuppeteerCrawler, ProxyConfiguration } from "crawlee";
let currentPage = 1;

(async () => {
    const requestQueue = await RequestQueue.open();
    const crawler = new PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestQueue,
        headless: true,
        maxRequestsPerMinute: 20,
        maxConcurrency: 5,
        proxyConfiguration: proxy ? new ProxyConfiguration({ proxyUrls: proxies }) : undefined,
        preNavigationHooks: [
            async (context, gotoOptions) => {
                gotoOptions.waitUntil = "domcontentloaded";
            },
        ],
        async requestHandler({ page, request }) {
            console.log("Requesting: " + request.url);
            if (request.label === "JD") {
                console.log("JOB: " + request.url);
                // console.log(request.userData);
                const title = await page.title();
                const resultsSelector = '.show-more-less-html__markup';
                await page.waitForSelector(resultsSelector);
                const jobDetails = await page.evaluate((resultsSelector, userData) => {
                    return {
                        ...userData,
                        description: document.querySelector(resultsSelector).innerHTML.trim(),
                        hiringOrganization: {
                            name: userData.hiringOrganization.name,
                            description: ""
                        },
                        type: "",
                        industry: ""
                    };

                    function getElementText(element) {
                        if (element) {
                            return element.textcontent || element.innerText || "";
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }, resultsSelector, request.userData);
                jobsData.push(jobDetails);
            } else {
                const resultsSelector = 'li';
                await page.waitForSelector(resultsSelector);
                const jobsList = await page.evaluate((resultsSelector, queryword, city) => {
                    return [...document.querySelectorAll(resultsSelector)].map((item, index) => {
                        let title = item.querySelector(".base-search-card__title");
                        let subtitle = item.querySelector(".base-search-card__subtitle");
                        let location = item.querySelector(".job-search-card__location");
                        let listdate = item.querySelector(".job-search-card__listdate");
                        let newlistdate = item.querySelector(".job-search-card__listdate--new");
                        let link = item.querySelector(".base-card__full-link");
                        return {
                            index,
                            title: getElementText(title),
                            subtitle: getElementText(subtitle),
                            description: "",
                            location: getElementText(location),
                            listdate: getElementText(listdate) || getElementText(newlistdate),
                            link: link && link.href ? link.href : "",
                            queryword: queryword,
                            hiringOrganization: {
                                name: getElementText(subtitle),
                                description: ""
                            },
                            type: "",
                            industry: "",
                            city: city
                        };
                    });

                    function getElementText(element) {
                        if (element) {
                            return element.textcontent || element.innerText || "";
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }, resultsSelector, queryword, location);

                console.log("[info]: Found", jobsList.length, "jobs on page", currentPage);
                // await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: jobsList[0].link, label: "JD", userData: jobsList[0] });
                // testing for one particular link
                await requestQueue.addRequests([{ url: jobsList[0].link, label: "JD", userData: jobsList[0] }]);

                if (Number(currentPage) < Number(pages)) {
                    console.log("[info] Getting page " + ++currentPage)
                }
            }
        }
    })

    console.log('[info]: Starting Crawler ' + url);
    let urls = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < pages; index++) {
        urls.push(getURL(index + 1));
    }
    if (urls.length < 1) {
        urls = [getURL(1)];
    }
    await crawler.run(urls);
    console.log("Saving JOBs Data");
    writeFileSync(resultFile, JSON.stringify(jobsData, null, 4));
})();
```

In the above else block is working perfectly as expected but not this if block `if (request.label === "JD") {`. There is a list of URLs passed to `await crawler.run(urls);` and then these pages will have one more link and it is collected using `link: link && link.href ? link.href : "",` This same URL is again passed to `await requestQueue.addRequests([{ url: jobsList[0].link, label: "JD", userData: jobsList[0] }]);`, It's should navigate to that page and evaluate as expected in If block.  `If` block is not working, please give me some hints.

```
    "crawlee": "^3.0.4",
    "puppeteer": "^15.1.1",
```